# substrate | try-runtime | sub-command | "fast-forward" | "ERROR main runtime: panicked at 'Timestamp slot must match `CurrentSlot`'"

Tags: substrate-node, try-runtime

I am currently in the process of integrating and testing the "try-runtime" feature on Starknet Madara.

https://github.com/keep-starknet-strange/madara/pull/690

However, I have encountered some challenges with the "fast-forward" sub-command. Specifically, I am receiving an error message stating "ERROR main runtime: panicked at 'Timestamp slot must match `CurrentSlot`'", originating from aura.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights regarding the potential cause of this issue, as well as guidance on how to resolve it.

> Commands and Traces used for execution:

**live**

```sh
export RPC_WS_URL="ws://127.0.0.1:9931" && \
export CHAIN_SPEC="./crates/node/chain-specs/madara-local-cfg2-raw.json" && \
RUST_LOG=runtime=trace,try-runtime::cli=trace,executor=trace \
cargo \
    run \
    --release \
    --features=try-runtime \
    --bin madara \
    -- \
    try-runtime \
    --runtime existing \
    --chain  "$CHAIN_SPEC" \
    fast-forward \
    --n-blocks=2 \
    --try-state=all \
    live \
    --uri  "$RPC_WS_URL"
```

"ERROR main runtime: panicked at 'Timestamp slot must match `CurrentSlot`"

[image]

**snap**

```sh
export RPC_WS_URL="ws://127.0.0.1:9931" && \
export SNAPSHOT_PATH="../000-01-install/madara-localnet.snap" && \
export CHAIN_SPEC="./crates/node/chain-specs/madara-local-cfg2-raw.json" && \
RUST_LOG=runtime=trace,try-runtime::cli=trace,executor=trace \
cargo \
    run \
    --release \
    --features=try-runtime \
    --bin madara \
    -- \
    try-runtime \
    --runtime existing \
    --chain  "$CHAIN_SPEC" \
    fast-forward \
    --block-ws-uri="$RPC_WS_URL" \
    --try-state=all \
    --n-blocks=2 \
    snap \
    --snapshot-path "$SNAPSHOT_PATH"
```

"ERROR main runtime: panicked at 'Timestamp slot must match `CurrentSlot`"

[image]

Comment: Please provide text output of errors too

Answer (score 0):

Yea some inherent from BABE or Aura errors out.
It is a known bug and tracked in [substrate#13831](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13831).

Comment: Noted, Thank you, @Oliver Tale-Yazdi